# Why was 'who is' omitted?

Tags: relative-pronouns

The sentence is:

> The driver is met by Jonuz, an Albanian, short in stature, but with thick shoulders and powerful arms.

Why is it not 'who is short in stature, but… arms.'?
Why is there no 'who is'?
What is this type of omission called?

Comment: Just like there's no "who is" before "an Albanian"

Comment: What is the grammatical terminology to explain this not that I understood anything from the comments.

Comment: What @AndyBonner said. Just like there's no *...but **who is** with thick shoulders and **who has** powerful arms.* I don't think there's a "term" for "not repeating oneself endlessly".

Comment: Goes without saying, so English drops it. For example, you didn't have to ask "Why don't we use the extra words 'who is' in this sentence, which leaves them out?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When "who is..." is included, that is a relative clause. The introduction to the clause can sometimes be omitted, and that is reduction of a relative clause, as described here:
[lemondgrad: How to reduce a relative clause](https://lemongrad.com/reduction-of-relative-clauses/)

Such clauses can be reduced to adjectives, or phrases of various types.

Comment: Thank you very much.